# Printing in Sleeping Barber using semaphores

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, pthreads, semaphore

I'm trying to implement a solution to the sleeping barber problem in C using pthreads and semaphores, only part of the requirement is that each action has to be printed out when it happens, such as:

- Barber has fallen asleep
- Customer has woken the barber up
- Customer is waiting for the barber
- Customer left because no seats were available (only to return a random period of time later)
- Customer is getting his hair cut
- Customer has left the store

I've been working at this problem for a little bit, only to get various deadlocks or having statements printed out-of-order.

The [classical solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeping_barber_problem#Implementation) for the problem wouldn't fully apply here because it would result in statements either being printed every time (e.g. "Barber has fallen asleep" followed by "customer has woken the barber up") or it would print statements out of order as a result of a context switch (which may or may not be a real issue).

My current solution, in pseudocode, is something like this:

```
int chairs       = N # available chairs
bool is_sleeping = false
bool is_cutting  = false 
bool finished    = false # All customers taken care of (Changed in main)

# Semaphores for read/write access
semaphore rw_chairs   = 1
semaphore rw_sleeping = 1
semaphore rw_cutting  = 1

semaphore barber_ready = 0 # Barber ready to cut hair
semaphore sleeping     = 0 # Barber is sleeping
semaphore cutting      = 0 # Barber cutting a customer's hair

def Barber():
   while not finished:
      wait(rw_chairs)
      wait(rw_sleeping)
      # If no chairs are being used
      if chairs == N:
         is_sleeping = true
         print("Barber is sleeping!")
         signal(rw_chairs)     # Allow others to read/write
         signal(rw_sleeping)
         wait(sleeping)        # Wait for customer to wake him up
         signal(barber_ready)  # Allow customers into the chair
         print("Barber woke up!")
      else:
         signal(rw_signal)
         chairs += 1
         signal(barber_ready)
         signal(rw_chairs)
      # If the barber isn't done for the day, help the customer
      if not finished:
         print("Helping a customer")
         # Wait a random amount of time
         print("Finished helping a customer")
         signal(cutting) # Let the customer leave after the hair cut
      else:
         print("Barber is done for the day!")

def Customer():
   bool helped = false
   while not helped:
      wait(rw_chairs)
      wait(rw_cutting)
      if chairs == N and not is_cutting: # If the barber is free
         wait(rw_sleeping)
         if is_sleeping:
            signal(sleeping) # Wake the barber up
            is_sleeping = false
            print("Customer has woken the barber up")
         signal(rw_sleeping)
         is_cutting = true
         signal(rw_chairs)
         signal(rw_cutting)
         wait(barber_ready) # Wait for the barber to be ready
         wait(cutting)      # Wait for him to finish cutting hair
         print("Customer has had his hair cut")
         helped = true
      else if chairs > 0:
         chairs -= 1
         print("Customer is waiting in a chair")
         signal(rw_chairs)
         signal(rw_cutting)
         wait(barber_ready)
         wait(cutting)
         print("Customer has had his hair cut")
         helped = true
      else:
         signal(rw_chairs)
         signal(rw_office)
         print("All chairs taken, will return later")
         # Wait a random amount of time 
   print("Customer is leaving the barbershop")
```

When this doesn't get a deadlock, using 3 chairs I get the following output:

```
Barber has fallen asleep
Customer is waiting in a chair
Customer is waiting in a chair
Customer is waiting in a chair
All chairs used, will return later
All chairs used, will return later
... (repeat the above line infinitely)
```

Its clear to me that the barber isn't properly letting a customer in -- but even in that I feel like my structure is all wrong. I think I'm approaching the problem wrong, and likely overcomplicating it.

If anyone here has any suggestions for how to build a working solution, or suggestions on restructuring my current one, that'd be greatly appreciated. Or if I'm on the right track, possibly a push in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working.

Seeing as I haven't seen this asked anywhere on here before, I will answer my own question in case anyone else comes across this looking for help like I did.

My original method wasn't entirely off, however there were some minor tweaks that were needed to get it to work properly. Instead of using 6 semaphores, I only used 5: 2 that control read/write access, and 3 that control queueing/sleeping.

The pseudocode is the following:

```
# Constants
SLEEPING = 0
AWAKE    = 1
BUSY     = 2

# Read/Write semaphores
Semaphore rw_chairs = 1      # Access to chairs
Semaphore rw_status = 1      # Access to barber status

# Access semaphores
Semaphore waiting   = 0      # Line for waiting customers
Semaphore cutting   = 0      # Semaphore to hold customer while getting hair cut
Semaphore sleeping  = 0      # Semaphore for barber to sleep

int   chairs        = n      # Available chairs to sit in
int   status        = AWAKE  # Barber Status (could also be a boolean for sleeping)
bool  finished      = false  # Is the program finished

def Barber():
   while not finished:
      wait(rw_chairs)
      wait(rw_status)
      # If there is nobody waiting and the barber isn't asleep
      if chairs == n and status != SLEEPING:
         barber = SLEEPING;
         print("Barber went to sleep!")
         signal(rw_status)
         signal(rw_chairs)
         wait(sleeping)    # Go to sleep
         print("Barber woke up!")
         signal(waiting)   # Let the next customer in
      else:
         signal(waiting)   # Let the next customer in
         chairs += 1       # Free the chair they sat in
         barber = BUSY     # Set the barber to busy
         signal(rw_status)
         signal(rw_chairs)

      # Once it gets here, the barber is awake and must help someone
      if not finished:
         print("Barber is cutting a customer's hair")
         # Cut the customer's hair
         print("Barber finished cutting the customer's hair")
         signal(cutting) # Release the customer so they can leave

    # barber's finally done
    print("Barber finished work for the day");

def Customer():
    bool helped = false

    print("Customer arrived at the Barber Shop!")
    while not helped:
       wait(rw_chairs)
       wait(rw_status)
       if chairs == n and status == SLEEPING:
          status = AWAKE
          print("Customer woke up the barber")
          signal(rw_status)
          signal(sleeping)  # Wake up the barber
          wait(waiting)     # Be the next customer to get helped (happens immediately)
          signal(rw_chairs)

          helped = true; // This customer is being helped
       else:
          signal(rw_status)
          if chairs > 0:
             chairs -= 1  # Claim a chair
             signal(rw_chairs)
             print("Customer sitting in a chair")
             wait(waiting) # Wait for the barber

             helped = true; // This customer is being helped
          else:
             print("Barber Shop is busy, will return later")
             signal(rw_chairs)
             # Wait a while before returning
       # If the customer is being helped
       if helped:
          print("Customer is getting a hair cut")
          wait(cutting)
          print("Customer is finished getting a haircut")
```

In main, once all the customer threads have been joined, it sets finished to true, and wakes up the (possibly) sleeping Barber to finish the program.

By this method, both the Barber and the Customer read chairs first followed by the status, and release it in the opposite order (preventing any deadlocks from circular waiting).